# CherryPy ThreadPool not growing and/or shrinking

Tags: python, cherrypy

I'm currently using CherryPy 3.2.2 and am having an issue where my ThreadPool does not grow and shrink at all. Looking through the source of [wsgiserver2.py](https://bitbucket.org/cherrypy/cherrypy/src/81c92cbcf2302f83efa739970a35ec48733b177c/cherrypy/wsgiserver/wsgiserver2.py?at=cherrypy-3.2.2) I see two functions in the ThreadPool class 'grow' and 'shrink'. If you download the entire repo and search for those two functions to see where they are being called they are not. Perhaps they are being invoked some other way that is foreign to me, but I would like to know if this is an oversight or I'm just looking in the wrong places.

Note: I'm setting the values (thread_pool and thread_pool_max) correctly before start is called on the Server, from the ServerAdapter, so its not that.

Thanks for all your help.

pcarl

Answer (score 2):

You're correct. Nor `ThreadPool.shrink` and `ThreadPool.grow` are being called in CherryPy flow, neither `thread_pool_max` has any effect unless you call these two methods explicitly.

Normally CherryPy will lazily instantiate thread workers up to `thread_pool` and will stop there.

If you're sure that you need big thread pool which causes serious memory overhead for your application you can inherit `cherrypy.process.plugins.Monitor` to monitor thread queue size or other parameter to grow and shrink the pool. Luckily there's already [one](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/cherrypy-dynpool) out there.